# How to change UI orientation without [UIDevice setValue:forKey:@"orientation"]

Tags: ios, orientation

My goal is changing lock/unlock orientation using button. In lock mode, orientation can be switched by button, and in unlock mode, orientation is determined by sensor.
I tried to achieve this with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation] forKey:@"orientation"]`, but this code has problem.
Assume that currently my app is 'Lock mode, portrait UI, portrait device'. Then I rotate device to landscape left, and unlock orientation. I expected `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` should be `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft`. But the value was `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait` though the real device is in landscape!

I tried also notification center with code below.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  
           addObserver:self  
              selector:@selector(onDeviceOrientationChanged:)  
                  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  
                object:nil];
```

But this code does not working properly. If the device is in landscape and UI orientation is set to portrait by `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait]`, `onDeviceOrientationChanged` is not called when I rotate device to portrait. I think device's orientation value is already set to portrait (by my code, not sensor).

ps. Of course, I checked **Required full screen** option.

**EDIT**: It would be also good answer to know how to get device's real orientation which is not affected by `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem using `MotionManager`. When I lock (or change) orientation, `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation] forKey:@"orientation"]` enough as usual.
However, when I unlock orientation, I refreshed orientation using `MotionManager` with below code.

```
CMMotionManager motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
    withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData * _Nullable accelerometerData, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];

        CMAcceleration acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation;
        if (acceleration.x >= 0.75) {
            orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        } else if (acceleration.x <= -0.75) {
            orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
        } else if (acceleration.y <= -0.75) {
            orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        } else if (acceleration.y >= 0.75) {
            orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];
        [UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
    }];
```

Of course, you should aware of `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` methods.

Comment: `UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];` this line has really helped me out. Thanks

Comment: @C0D3LIC1OU5 Thank you for your comment, I would have overlooked that line. That's all I needed too!

Comment: FYI, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473584/1010443) is very helpful to understand iOS orientation mechanism.